# USB device found on embedded device but unable to mount

Tags: embedded, usb

I have a embedded device running linux 2.6.27 on an arm machine. The kernel and system is working correctly AFIK. I plugged in a USB flash drive and it detects the drive (following output).

```
scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler II  PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 2014208 512-byte hardware sectors (1031 MB)
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 2014208 512-byte hardware sectors (1031 MB)
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I can see that it creates device node is created under sda but I cant find any sda device in /dev/. But I can see it under /sys/sda. I tried mounting using the following command:
    mount -t vfat /dev/sda/ /mnt/

This fails saying /dev/sda no file found (as it's not there in /dev). Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What does 'df -h' print out for the drive?

Comment: Here is the output:    ` Filesystem  Size  Used Available Use     %      Mounted on
    /dev/root                 1.0G     84.2M    939.8M   8% /
    tmpfs                    29.5M         0     29.5M   0% /dev `

Comment: I think that is saying its under /dev/root. Can you try running the mount command on that instead of /dev/sda ?

Comment: Actually even /dev/root isnt there (No device or file error).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need udev for dynamic device node creation. If udev is present on the system, check if you have custom rules at /etc/udev/rules.d/.